# Set python variable from result of SQL query

Tags: python, mysql

I am playing with python for the first time on the raspberry pi.

I have a script that queries an SQL table and returns the value that is set.

What I can not get to work is setting the python variable from the results.

Here is part of the code I have

```
# execute SQL query using execute() method.
cursor.execute("select id from wallboard")

# Fetch a single row using fetchone() method.
data = cursor.fetchone()

# disconnect from server
db.close()

result = str("%s " % data)
print result

if result == 1:
```

The print displays the result okay but it is not going into the if statement.

I am very new to python so its possibly a simple fix but I'm stumped.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Don't convert the result to string:

```
>>> "1" == 1
False
```

Also note that `fetchone()` would return you a single row of results which would be represented as a tuple - get the first item to get the actual `id` column value:

```
result = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

Comment: Pay careful attention to type in Python (depending on what lang you come from this may be a little weird). Use Pythons's ```type(var)``` - I have those statements all over early builds still. Also key is ```isinstance()``` to determine if is a type of string/class/etc or instance of specific class name.

Comment: @BK435 the advice is entirely use-case specific. The OP compares the result of the SQL query which returns an integer id with integer `1`. There is no point in making an intermediate string.